# What is the best way to calculate field values with a function? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have some fields in an AngularJS form that need to record a total percentage.  Form example;

Gender split of a group - % Males, % Females

Currently I am using a field for each gender.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
   <label for="male">% Male:<span class="error">*</span></label>
      <input type="number"
             name="males"
             max="100"
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="newReport.males"
             required>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="female">% Female:<span class="error">*</span></label>
       <input type="number"
              class="form-control"
              ng-model="newReport.females"
              ng-readonly="true"
              value="@{{ females() }}"
              placeholder="@{{ females() }}"
              required>
</div>
```

Then I use this function to calculate the Female %

```
$scope.females = function() {
    return 100 - this.newReport.males;
};
```

However, my ng-model="newReport.females" never seems to get set.  The placeholder does get the correct value from the function but won't persist since the model is not picking it up.

Is there a better way to do this?  Also, once I am getting it to set the model properly, what is the best way to validate that the 2 fields add up to 100?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have an input for both, if one is computed from the other? The second input's model is `newReport.females`, but the code never sets that value, so why do you expect the field to display the female ratio?

Comment: That makes sense.  So I guess this begs a simpler question.  How do I assign the value from the function to newReport.females?

Comment: Again, why use a separate field when newReport.males contain everything you need. Don't use an input for the femaled ratio, and just use what you already use to display the computed femal ratio: {{ females() }}

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  I do need to display the female ratio to he user and persist it when the form is submitted.  So, I guess the question now is how do I assign the value from the function to the newReport.females value?

Comment: `this.newReport.females = $scope.females();`

Comment: Here's the mega noob question.  Where?  I have tried in the function itself after the computation and as it's own function.  No dice.

Comment: You must have a submit() function (or whatever you named it) that is called by the ng-clink of a button or by the ng-submit of the form, when it's submitted. Put that line of code in that function, before sending this.newReport to the backend.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks JB.